# Спойлер на основе JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый вечер! Не могу понять, почему если я делаю несколько , функция не хочет открывать спойлер для последующих div . То есть копирую  код 5 раз, но спойлер открывает только в 1 диве, по щелчку на второй, третий, четвертый и пятый они отказываются работать. На какой бы не нажал, открывается 1-ый и все. Заранее спасибо.

```js
var flag = 0;

function spoiler() {
  var text = document.getElementById("spoilerText");
  var button = document.getElementById("spoilerButton");


  if (flag == 0) {
    text.style.height = "100px";
    flag = 1;
    // console.log(flag);

  } else {
    text.style.height = "0px";
    flag = 0;
  }

}
```

```css
.spoilerButton {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: width 1s;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.spoilerButton:hover {
    background: black;
}
.spoilerText {
    width: 70%;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background: #0081d7;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s;
    text-align: left;
}
span {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Нельзя задавать несколько одинаковых id на странице

Comment: Потому что id должны быть уникальные, поэтому ваш код срабатывает только на первый блок

Comment: @Cheg Разобрался, спасибо, но как прописать можно остальные id в одной JS функции? Не копировать же каждый JS код с разными значениями..

Comment: в место ID используй CLASS и прокрути в цикле

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Про уникальные id уже сказано в комментариях, поэтому сразу перейду к решению.

Для того, что указать на то, открыт спойлер или закрыт, вместо флага лучше добавлять или удалять определенный класс этому спойлеру, например, `.active`, и проверку осуществлять уже по наличию данного класса:

```js
function hasClass(elem, className) { // проверка на hasClass
  return new RegExp(' ' + className + ' ').test(' ' + elem.className + ' ');
}

function spoiler(el) {
  var text = el.parentNode.querySelector(".spoilerText"); // находим .spoilerText в полученном элементе 

  if (!hasClass(text, 'active')) {
    text.style.height = "100px";
    text.classList.add('active');

  } else {
    text.style.height = "0px";
    text.classList.remove('active');
  }

}
```

```css
.spoilerButton {
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: width 1s;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.spoilerButton:hover {
  background: black;
}

.spoilerText {
  width: 70%;
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  background: #0081d7;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s;
  text-align: left;
}

span {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
      <span>Click for open</span>
    </div>
    <div class="spoilerText">
      <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
      <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
        <span>Click for open</span>
      </div>
      <div class="spoilerText">
        <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
          <span>Click for open</span>
        </div>
        <div class="spoilerText">
          <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="text">
          <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)">
            <span>Click for open</span>
          </div>
          <div class="spoilerText">
            <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Согласно стандарту HTML на всей странице не должно быть одинаковых атрибутов `ID`. Вы не можете использовать `id="spoilerButton"` несколько раз на странице. Более того вы не сможете узнать так, на какой элемент вы нажали. Это можно узнать только из объекта события `event` которое передается в `onclick`.

Но и тут Вас подстерегает проблема, Вам нужен не только текущий элемент, но и находящийся следом за ним текстовый элемент. Его можно попробовать получить пройдя по дереву дальше через `nextSibling`, но и это тоже неустойчивая конструкция. Потому что текстовый пустой элемент между `div` тоже считается при проходе по дереву и выглядит это так `nextSibling.nextSibling`.

А еще у Вас разметка лесенкой, так как вы не закрываете `<div class="text">`. Ниже я даю исправленный вариант, а еще ниже как лучше делать с вложенными элементами, что бы по детям дерева не ходить.

```js
var flag = 0;

function spoiler() {
  var text = event.currentTarget.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  var button = event.currentTarget;

  if (flag == 0) {
    text.style.height = "100px";
    flag = 1;
    // console.log(flag);

  } else {
    text.style.height = "0px";
    flag = 0;
  }

}
```

```css
.spoilerButton {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: width 1s;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.spoilerButton:hover {
    background: black;
}
.spoilerText {
    width: 70%;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background: #0081d7;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s;
    text-align: left;
}
span {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
```

Поэтому лучше все таки помещать элементы один в другой и искать по классам.

```js
var flag = 0;

function spoiler() {
  var button = event.currentTarget;
  var text = button.getElementsByClassName("spoilerText")[0];
  

  if (flag == 0) {
    text.style.height = "100px";
    flag = 1;
    // console.log(flag);

  } else {
    text.style.height = "0px";
    flag = 0;
  }

}
```

```css
.text{
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.spoilerButton {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: width 1s;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.spoilerButton:hover {
    background: black;
}
.spoilerText {
    width: 70%;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background: #0081d7;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s;
    text-align: left;
}
span {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <div class="spoilerButton">Click for open</div>
    <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
      <span>
         The printing andtypesetting industry.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <div onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <div class="spoilerButton">Click for open</div>
    <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
      <span>
         The printing andtypesetting industry.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="text">
  <div onclick="spoiler()" id="spoilerButton">
    <div class="spoilerButton">Click for open</div>
    <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
      <span>
         The printing andtypesetting industry.
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Помогло решить мою проблему.

Comment: @OlegSevernuy опять же, 2 раза нужно кликнуть

Comment: @Cheg уже заметил, в чем загвоздка интересно(

Answer (score 1):

Передавай в `onclick` функцию `this` и потом ищи следующего соседа (естественно работает только для текущей разметки)

```js
var flag = 0;

function spoiler( button ) {
  const text = button.nextElementSibling;

  if (flag == 0) {
    text.style.height = "100px";
    flag = 1;
    // console.log(flag);

  } else {
    text.style.height = "0px";
    flag = 0;
  }

}
```

```css
.spoilerButton {
    width: 85%;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    background: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: width 1s;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.spoilerButton:hover {
    background: black;
}
.spoilerText {
    width: 70%;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background: #0081d7;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s;
    text-align: left;
}
span {
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="text">
  <div class="spoilerButton" onclick="spoiler(this)" id="spoilerButton">
    <span>Click for open</span>
  </div>
  <div class="spoilerText" id="spoilerText">
    <span>
The printing andtypesetting industry.
</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Вы предлагаете по 2 раза щелкать на элемент?

Comment: @Cheg, это из-за `flag` мне неведомо зачем там эта переменная и это вроде не входило в задачу.

Comment: Если это не входило в задачу, вы считаете допустимым остать все так?

Comment: @Cheg, я считаю, что если чего-то нет - возможно надо добавить, если что-то есть - возможно оно кому-то нужно.

Comment: Действительно нужно 2 раза кликать на открытие